# detect if key is pressed from script

Tags: scripting, x11, keyboard, xte

I would like to detect if a key is being pressed when running a script. I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 0.5
xte 'str sometext'
```

I run this script using a shortcut to paste "sometext" where I'm at in kde. I used a sleep 0.5 here because the script itself is run with a shortcut that uses ctrl and alt. If the sleep 0.5 is omitted, the result is that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, etc... is sent. I think the solution would be to add some bussy wait at the beginning that would block untill no keys are being pressed. How can I get this to work in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using xte anyways, why not release the keys with xte? Something along the lines

```
xte "keyup Control_L"
xte "keyup l"
```

(assuming your shortcut is ctrl-l).

Comment: ok this works for the alt key and control key, the only problem is that I have my capslock be another control key so the keyup on the control leaves the capslock down. I have searched for a way to keyup capslock but this seems not to be possible with xte. any suggestions?